# How to remove jQuery-ui code from string

Tags: objective-c, jquery-ui, rss

I am parsing an RSS feed and inside the content i get this:

> jQuery(document).ready(function(){ var options = { sites : new
>   Array("facebook","twitter","gplus","linkedin","stumpleupon"),
>   plugin_url : "http://www.examplewebsite.com/" };
>   load_all_in_one_social_banner(options); });
>   and here is my content.

how am I going to remove this jQuery-ui code from my string?

Comment: is that a XXX web site? Nice, sorry to deviate tough.!

Comment: If this jQuery-UI code is exactly the same for all of your contents, you could split the string in two at the index matching the end of this code?

Comment: @Ishank oh shit, i'm so sorry. never realize that it is an inappropriate website. i was just simply giving a name for it. my bad...

Comment: @Bigood nope, i'm getting rss from a lot of websites, so probably this could happen to any other websites also.